# Update-Database connection string issue

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

We have a code-first entity framework project and an associated app.config file.

The connection string points to a SQL Azure instance. When we deploy the app into a Cloud Service and ask it to auto-create the database it does so, but does not appear to run the Configuration code as we are seeing empty tables.

When I run "update-database" from a Dev VM hosted in Azure, I get the following error:

> An error occurred while getting provider information from the
>   database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect
>   connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure
>   that the connection string is correct.

With further details of

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. 
This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. 
Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. 
---> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. 
---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher
```

Yet it is the same connection string we have used in the deployed instance to create the database.

Any suggestions as to why update-database is failing?

Comment: How do you run it? There are several ways to give a connection string to migrations commands

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database uses SQL Logins so the user id and password are in the connection string.  If you don't have Persist Security Info=True then the credentials get lost inside EF.  This is something that was broken I think in EF 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be helpful so here is the workaround we use.  We implement Dispose on our DbContext and restore the connection string after the context is disposed so the migration doesn't later choke:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            _disposed = true;
            var connection = Database.Connection;
            var connectionString = Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
    }
```